# Understanding COVARIANCE when using same scale

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, variance, covariance

Assuming that an experiment has 3 variables.

Time, Temperature inside, Temperature outside.
Also, considering that both the temperatures are measured using the same scale say Degree Celsius.

If the covariance ,

Cov (Time and Temperature inside) **>** Cov (Time and Temperature outside)

What is the **intuitive meaning of this relation**.
I understand that we can conclusively say something about this relation (**no need of correlation strength**) **since both the temperatures are measured using the same scale**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a clarifying question: why measure covariance between time and temperature (inside or outside)? I fail to see what insight this measure will give you.

Comment: For example, I need to understand how the temperature increases/decrease Inside and outside the house as the day progresses. And in that context what does the following mean ?
Cov (Time and Temperature inside) > Cov (Time and Temperature outside)

Comment: What exactly you would like to extract from those timeseries? I would compute correlation between the two temperature timeseries, it would provide the time moments where temperature increases/decreases at the same time (positive) and where its opposite (negative).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @xeon.
I understand what I was missing. Though both the temperatures are measured in degree Celsius, comparing the covariance of two temperature time series don't provide any intelligible information as long as the **signs** are same. 
Correlation is the way to go.